# jQuery/JavaScript: selecting first "layer" of children only

Tags: jquery, nested, selector

I'm trying to select only the first "layer" of children elements of a given type, but not elements nested inside another qualifying element. E.g. in:

```
<div id='top'>
  <div id="s1" class="special">
    <div id="s2" class="special"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div id="s3" class="special"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to find #s1 and #s3, but not #s2, with something like $('#top').find('.special:not_nested'). Is it possible with jQuery? XPATH?

I thought about jQuery custom filters like expr[':'].not_nested, but can't figure out how to take into account the top parent ($('#top') in this case), because there may be other .special classes further up in the parent chain of #top.

[edit] I should mention right now I'm resorting to a recursive call to $.fn.children() which I think is not very efficient.

[edit2] tested working code:

```
    var node = $('#top'),
    result = (node.find('.special').filter(function(){
       return !($(this).parent().closest(".special", node).length);
    }));
```

However, this doesn't work if "#top" has .special class itself. So maybe this:

```
var node = $('#top'),
result= node.find('.special').filter(function(){
   var parent = $(this).parent().closest(".special", node);
   return !parent.length || parent.is(node);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option is to use `.children()` in place of `.find()`, but it will have the same result as idrumgood's solution.

```
$('#top').children('.special')
```

Edit: i just realized the nesting of `#s3`, this may work for that situation:

```
$('#top').find('.special').filter(function(){
  return $(this).closest('.special').length === 0;
}).doSomething()
```

Edit2: here ya go:

```
$('#top').find('.special').filter(function(){
   return !$(this).parent().closest(".special").closest("#top").length;
}).doSomething;
```

Comment: This won't work as it finds direct children only, I need to find grandchildren, as long as they're not nested under another children/grandchildren of ".special".

Comment: Your edited code won't work either. As I mentioned in the question there may be ".special" nodes further up parent chain of "#top".

Comment: I guess I missed that little bit too. The newest edit should take that into account.

Comment: I was just thinking along those lines when I read your second edit. I think if you change it to return !$(this).parent().closest(".special", $("#top")).legnth it'll work. I'll need to evaluate the performance of this vs what I'm doing now. I'm marking yours as the answer since it should return the correct set.

Comment: I would expect this to be the most efficient: `!$(this).parent().closest("#top .special").length`

Comment: Good thinking, and it would resolve the situation with .special on #top itself - except #top is only an example here and will be a variable in the actual situation. Pls check out my edit2 about #top having .special on itself, any thoughts how to improve on it? I'm not  sure about the checking.

Comment: That works only if #top has the class .special, it doesn't work in your original case.

Comment: What is throwing a wrench in this whole situation is `.closest()` will return the current element if the current element matches the selector in `.closest()`.

Answer (score 3):

`$('#top > .special');` the `>` is only direct decedents.

Except your code has `#s3` also nested inside a secondary div, so I'm not sure if you're really wanting what you asked.

Comment: #s3 isn't nested inside another ".special" div. I'm trying to select unnested ".specials", not unnested divs. That's the reason for this question...

Comment: See Kevin B's answer. Using a function in the .filter function to test for a .special parent should do the trick

Comment: Please see my comment under Kevin B's answer why the filter doesn't work. The last part in my original question explains it too.

Answer (score 0):

If it's specifically those divs, you might want to try using css selectors with spaces, like

```
".one .three" and ".one"
```

for something like this

```
<div class="one">
    <div class="two">
         <div class="three">
```