# JavaScript | jQuery | Selecting In Layers: Select Closest Children But Their Children

Tags: javascript, jquery, children, closest

The goal is to select any descendant(s) -- *regardless of direct-descendant indication* -- but not their children. In other words, if I'm searching from `document` I'd like to find *all children which are **not** wrapped by the target selector*:

```
<div id="a1" class="scenario-1" data-behavior="test">
    test
    <div id="a2" data-behavior="test">
        test 1
        <div id="a3" data-behavior="test">
            test 2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="scenario-2">
    <div id="b1" data-behavior="test">
        test 1
        <div id="b2" data-behavior="test">
            test 2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

$(document).findAllInFirstLayer([data-behavior]);
```

This, ideally, would select `#a1` & `#b1` in the result-set. However, `#a2`, `#a3`, and `#b2` should not be included, as this would proceed *one scope to many*.

The complimentary function for this will be recursive to drill down to the next scope for *each layer-element* in the set. So the next recursive call would return a set containing `#a2`, `#b2`, but not `#a3` or any children (`[data-behavior]`) of `#b2`.

Also, this Question should *not* be marked as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391925/jquery-javascript-selecting-first-layer-of-children-only) as the Accepted-Answer is *not* acceptable here -- the accepted answer here should use a jQuery selector or prove its impossibility with only using a jQuery selector.

#### Edit

With @guest271314's help, we reached the following answer:

```
'[data-behavior]:not([data-behavior] [data-behavior]), [data-behavior]:first'
```

Now, a recursive function can be used to take a parent-context and find the *first-level scopes* -- and recur in that fashion indefinitely. Here's an example:

```
arm: function autoRegisterModules(parent) {
    var $firstScope = $(parent).find('[data-behavior]:not([data-behavior] [data-behavior]), [data-behavior]:first');
    console.log('#context, #first-scope', parent, $firstScope);
    if ($firstScope.length) {
        $firstScope.each(function (i, p) {
            autoRegisterModules(p);
        });
    }
},
```

Please be sure to give credit where it's due.

#prethanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This, ideally, would select `#a1` & `#b1` in the result-set.

Try using `:not()` for first result set , `:first` for next results

```js
var first = $("[data-behavior]:not([data-behavior] [data-behavior])"),
  second = first.find("[data-behavior]:first"),
  third = second.find("[data-behavior]:first");

console.log(first, second, third);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="a1" class="scenario-1" data-behavior="test">
  test
  <div id="a2" data-behavior="test">
    test 1
    <div id="a3" data-behavior="test">
      test 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="scenario-2">
  <div id="b1" data-behavior="test">
    test 1
    <div id="b2" data-behavior="test">
      test 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

> So the next recursive call would return a set containing `#a2`, `#b2`, but not `#a3` or any children (`[data-behavior]`) of `#b2`.

using `$.fn.extend()`

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.extend({
    layers: function(sel) {
      var root, next, res = [],
        sel = sel || this.selector;
      if ($(sel + ":not(" + sel + " " + sel + ")").length) {
        root = $(sel + ":not(" + sel + " " + sel + ")");
        res.push([root]);
        if (root.find(sel + ":first").length) {
          next = root.find(sel + ":first");
          res.push([next]);
          while (next.find(sel + ":first").length) {
            next = next.find(sel + ":first");
            res.push([next])
          }
        }
      }
      return this.data("layers", res)
    }
  })
}(jQuery))

var layers = $("[data-behavior]").layers().data("layers");
$.each(layers, function(key, value) {
  console.log(key, value[0])
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="a1" class="scenario-1" data-behavior="test">
  test
  <div id="a2" data-behavior="test">
    test 1
    <div id="a3" data-behavior="test">
      test 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="scenario-2">
  <div id="b1" data-behavior="test">
    test 1
    <div id="b2" data-behavior="test">
      test 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works well for the first scope (`var $first = $(document).find('...')`), but when I run `$($first[0]).find('...')` it doesn't find anything... Any ideas? Think your answer is close. Would you mind elaborating on the selector, please?

Comment: @Cody See updated post. First selector selects `data-behavior` that is not descendant of  `data-behavior` ; second selector matches first child element `data-behavior` found from results of first matched selectors

Comment: That's almost it!!! I modified & combined both of your selectors and that did the trick! Here's what I've: 
`'[data-behavior]:not([data-behavior] [data-behavior]), [data-behavior]:first'`. 
If you don't mind, I'd like you to add this in your answer -- optimize it if needed (corner-cases?) -- so I can accept your answer as I think you deserve the credit.